# Reddit API poll for comments where a username has been tagged

Tags: reddit

I have checked http://www.reddit.com/dev/api but I am a complete Reddit newbie and I am not familiar with the terminology.

If you'd want to poll Reddit for all comments that have your username tagged, which API call would you use?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same thing, let me know if you're able to figure it out.

Comment: If someone mentions your username, using the reddit user syntax, like /u/bbozo, you will receive a message in your inbox with the subject `username mention` and the message will be the comment (IIRC, the thing_id is a t1 for that comment). You can just have your app check the inbox for these messages, and then if there is a comment in there from a username mention, then act accordingly